# How do I specify the network ID in the config file when migrating/testing contracts on my local ganache?

Tags: truffle, testing, ganache, truffle-test, ganache-cli

So my issue is when I run the `compile` and then `migrate` commands everything goes smooth, then I try to test by running the `truffle test` command and it gives me an error saying 'Error: The network id specified in the truffle config (4447) does not match the one returned by the network (5777)'. This is what is in my config file at the moment:

```
module.exports = {
  localGanache: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 7545,
      from: '0xFE50B4F7B2921454E9204596b295d2B3648CF421',
      network_id: "5777",
      gas: 6721975
    },
```

Do I need to have a separate config file set up for testing? If so what does it look like?
Thanks in advance for help and sorry my newbie skills

Answer (score 5):

You can set the ganache-cli network ID by using a flag when running it:

```
ganache-cli --networkId 4447
```

Answer (score 1):

As said by @shane you can run the command with the `networkId` flag or alternatively you can change your config to '*' to match any id provided by ganache.